# Photos not displaying in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here is App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Search from './Search';
import Nav from './Nav';
import '../index.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import apiKey from './Config';
import NotFound from './NotFound';
import PhotoList from './PhotoList';


class App extends Component {

  state= {
    pictures: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getImages()
  }


  getImages=(query='cats')=> {
    axios.get(`https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=${apiKey}&tags=${query}&per_page=24&page=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`)
      .then(res=> {
        const pictures=res.data.photos.photo
        this.setState({pictures});
      }).catch((error)=> {
        console.log("There was an error parsing your data", error);
      })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.pictures);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Search />
        <Nav getImages={this.getImages}  />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={()=> <Redirect to={'/cats'} />} />
          <Route path='/cats' render={()=> <PhotoList getImages={()=>this.getImages} query='cats' data={this.state.pictures}/>} />
          <Route path='/dogs' render={()=> <PhotoList getImages={()=>this.getImages} query='dogs' data={this.state.pictures} />} />
          <Route path='/computers' render={()=> <PhotoList getImages={()=>this.getImages} query='computers' data={this.state.pictures} />} />
          <Route component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is PhotoList.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Photo from './Photo';

class PhotoList extends Component {

  handleImages=()=> {
    this.props.getImages(this.props.query);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleImages();
  }


  render() {
    const data=this.props.data 
    console.log(this.props.query)
    return (
      <div className="photo-container">
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <ul>
          {data.map((photo,index)=> 
            <Photo 
              farm={photo.farm}
              server={photo.server} 
              id={photo.id}
              secret={photo.secret}
              key={index}
            />
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default PhotoList;
```

I've passed the getImages function into PhotoList that fetches data and changes the main App's state. The function takes a query string (cats, dogs, or computers). Then the state data is passed down as props and mapped over in the PhotoList component.

My website still only displays cats, even when I type in a different path (ex /dogs, /computers), yet when I console log the query string, I'm clearly entering different values into it. So why am I still getting cats shown? I know by default the query is equal to cats, but when I call the function in PhotoList it should be set to a different value with the query prop.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show me the results of console.log?

Comment: @Antonio I just edited my post. Take a look.

Comment: I think that is because componentDidMount function is called only once. Please check that.

Comment: @Antonio well yeah I want it to call the function as soon as the component is mounted, and then the component should render again when it receives the new data from state. Is there something wrong with the logic?

Answer (score 1):

In your codes `this.handleImages` is called only once because componentDidMount is only called when the component firstly initialized by props.

To get various types of images, you need to call when the prop is changed.

Then you can use `componentDidUpdate` function to do that.

```
   componentDidMount() {
     this.handleImages();
   }

   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
     if (prevProps.query !== this.props.query) {
       this.handleImages();
     }
   }
```

Comment: My POV was that once the route detects the path match, component gets placed on the DOM and you call the getImage function once with componentDidMount (which of course makes sense). But even its called once, its still passing in the correct query to handle images no? Then the component would simply render again because the data in the state changed and its being passed down as props. Isn't this perfectly allowed to happen in react?

Comment: You misunderstood react, *React* means that call render in your component when props or state value is changed but doesn't mean that call functions in `componentDidMount`. But you can use `componentDidUpdate` to call your functions at that time.

Comment: No I totally get that you call render in your component when the props or state value changes. Are you saying that if you have a function inside componentDidMount, the function will NOT get called as soon as the PhotoList component gets mounted on the DOM? If so, when will it invoke the function inside of it? Please let me know.

Comment: `componentDidMount` is called only once when your component is mounted firstly. When props or state is changed, `componentDidUpdate` function is called after rerender. :D

Comment: @Antontio Okay thank you. By the way I pasted this code into my work, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Could you check if `getImages` in app.js is called when you changed the router?